# Show that a solution to an equation set is also a solution to another equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$y=\frac12x^2;\;
y^2+(x-3)^2=3^2$ (circle)

The function and circle intersect at two points, one is $(0,0)$ and lets say the other is $(x_0,y_0)$
Show that $x=x_0$ is also a solution to the equation $x^3+4x=24$.

I dont understand at all how to solve this. I tried solving
$(x^3+4x-24)/(x-x_0)$ and try and get a new expression for $x_0$(?) since there can't be any remainder, but then I just end up with the exact same equation, in terms of $x_0$ instead.

Comment: Typo, I fixed the circle equation and took away the double -+

Answer (score 3):

If $y = \frac 1 2 x^2$ then we can substitute for $y$ in the equation of the circle to get:

$\frac 1 4 x^4 + (x-3)^2 = 9
\\ \Rightarrow x^4 + 4x^2 - 24x + 36 = 36
\\ \Rightarrow x(x^3 + 4x - 24) = 0
\\ \Rightarrow x=0 \text{ or } x^3 + 4x - 24=0$

Answer (score 0):

Given $y=\frac12x^2\iff x=\sqrt{2y} \tag{1}$
$y^2+(x-3)^2=3^2 \tag{2}$

$$\quad y^2+(x-3)^2=3^2\\ 
\implies (x^2-6x+9)+y^2-9=0\\
\implies x^2-6x+y^2=0\\
\implies \frac{6\pm\sqrt{36-4y^2}}{2} \\
x=3\pm\sqrt{3^3-y^2}\qquad y^2\le 3^3\\
\implies x\in\big\{0,3,6\big\}$$

We now try $x$-values into $(1)$ and we get we get
$$y=\frac{x^2}{2}\implies y=0\quad y=4.5 \quad y=18$$

Since $y\le 3$, the only integer solution is $\space (0,0)\space$ but we can use your results $\space  (x^3 + 4 x - 24) = 0\quad$
with WolframAlpha as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E3+%2B+4+x+-+24%29+%3D+0) $\text{to find}\space x\approx 2.42682\quad$ Equation $(1)$ now shows $y\approx2.94474$

We could also feed the original equations to WolframAlpha for [both values](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E2%2B%28x-3%29%5E2+-+3%5E2%3D0%2C+y%3D%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E2%7D%7B2%7D) or use the cubic equation (tedious) to find the one real solution for $x.\qquad$ For $x^2+4x-24=0\space$ we let
$$a=1,\space b=0,\space c=4,\space d=-24$$
and
$$x=\sqrt[\Large{3}]{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3 }+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)+\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3}+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)^2+\biggl(\frac{c}{3a}-\frac{b^2}{9a^2}\biggr)^3}}\\
+\sqrt[\Large{3}]{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3 }+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)-\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3}+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)^2+\biggl(\frac{c}{3a}-\frac{b^2}{9a^2}\biggr)^3}}-\frac{b}{3a}$$

I have used the cubic equation and it works but there are sometimes intermediate complex components that require robust software such as WolframAlpha or Python to get results.